# Webpack "cannot find module" error, path is wrong

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am trying to publish my application and I am getting the following webpack error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\source\repos\DDvwn\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js'

The path it provides is wrong. The correct path to the file should be C:\Users\User\source\repos\DDvwn\**DDvwn**\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js, with another "DDVwn" subfolder present in the hierarchy. I am not seeing a place to change this in the config file and my searches online haven't been fruitful.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can we see your webpack configure code and your package.json, to get some idea of how your production code starts up?